# link helpers, current_pages and navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying keep a tab on a page to be selected by checking the controller.
I.e., any page that displays the `Products` controller should keep the `Product` tab selected.
I can't seem to find the right approach.
I was considering of making a helper method, but it seems a bit tricky to put the helper into my `link_to` helper. Here is my guess of how I can make it work:

```
<%= link_to "Products", products_path, current_controller?('products') ? :class => 'selected' %>
```

Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the problem wont just be in one place, you'll have many tabs and each tabs will have rules on which controllers+action combinations it would be active/selected for.

It's a common problems and some people have written "plugins" for the same too.

I suggest you write helpers. Make your own mini DSL. Decide for yourself what is easy and nice to look at:

```
<%= link_to_tab_for("Products", products_path, :controller => "sss", :action => "", :other_html_options => {})
```

Next step, implement this method in helpers/application.rb

```
def link_to_tab_for(name, path, options)
  controller = options.delete(:controller)
  action = options.delete(:controller)
  klass = [].push(options[:class]).compact
  if current_controller?(controller) && (action ? current_action?(action) : true)
    klass.push("selected")
  end
  options[:class] = klass.empty ? "" : klass.join(" ")
  link_to(name, path, options)
end
```

Have a gander at attempting the above method to your liking of course.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am doing something very similar to this. JD